# Talking to salesforce with Django through the REST API

Tags: python, django, rest, salesforce

I have to talk with a salesforce platform and I would like to use their REST API. However the salesforce website only provides examples for Ruby and PHP but I am working with Python (Django).

Can someone provide the minimal code that is needed to connect to salesforce and send a simple request with Python?

Comment: have you tried using https://github.com/neworganizing/simple-salesforce?

Comment: Exactly what I need. Can you put this link in an answer?

Comment: no problem, just did it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using this library. Salesforce endorses it, and there's pretty good documentation available.

http://github.com/neworganizing/simple-salesforce

Comment: is this a django code ?